# Decreasing loss for epochs but accuracy remains same for multiple epochs before changing

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, tf.keras

I am building a neural network model to identify the blade sharpness based on the cutting force at the given distance after incision. My data is in csv format and I am using a binary classification model with 2 hidden layers. I only 45 input data points. When I run I my neural network model the loss is decreasing but the accuracy remains same over multiple epochs before changing.

```
#Initialising the neural network
Classifier = Sequential()

#Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
Classifier.add(Dense(units=2, kernel_initializer= 'he_uniform', activation= 'relu',input_dim = 2))

Classifier.add(Dense(units=2, kernel_initializer= 'he_uniform', activation= 'relu',))


#Adding the output layer
Classifier.add(Dense(units =1, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation = 'sigmoid',))


Classifier.summary()
```

````
Epoch 177/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 98ms/step - loss: 0.5921 - accuracy: 0.7222 - val_loss: 0.6642 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 178/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 72ms/step - loss: 0.5915 - accuracy: 0.7222 - val_loss: 0.6627 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 179/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 83ms/step - loss: 0.5908 - accuracy: 0.7222 - val_loss: 0.6612 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 180/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 82ms/step - loss: 0.5902 - accuracy: 0.7222 - val_loss: 0.6597 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 181/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 123ms/step - loss: 0.5896 - accuracy: 0.7222 - val_loss: 0.6581 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 182/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 77ms/step - loss: 0.5889 - accuracy: 0.7222 - val_loss: 0.6566 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 183/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 75ms/step - loss: 0.5883 - accuracy: 0.7500 - val_loss: 0.6550 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 184/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 73ms/step - loss: 0.5877 - accuracy: 0.8056 - val_loss: 0.6533 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 185/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 83ms/step - loss: 0.5870 - accuracy: 0.8056 - val_loss: 0.6517 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 186/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 103ms/step - loss: 0.5864 - accuracy: 0.8056 - val_loss: 0.6500 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 187/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 95ms/step - loss: 0.5857 - accuracy: 0.8056 - val_loss: 0.6484 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 188/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 69ms/step - loss: 0.5851 - accuracy: 0.8056 - val_loss: 0.6467 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 189/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 84ms/step - loss: 0.5845 - accuracy: 0.8056 - val_loss: 0.6450 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 190/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 94ms/step - loss: 0.5838 - accuracy: 0.8056 - val_loss: 0.6433 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 191/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 86ms/step - loss: 0.5832 - accuracy: 0.8056 - val_loss: 0.6416 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 192/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 80ms/step - loss: 0.5825 - accuracy: 0.8056 - val_loss: 0.6399 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 193/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 63ms/step - loss: 0.5818 - accuracy: 0.8056 - val_loss: 0.6381 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 194/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 79ms/step - loss: 0.5812 - accuracy: 0.8056 - val_loss: 0.6364 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 195/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 87ms/step - loss: 0.5805 - accuracy: 0.8056 - val_loss: 0.6347 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 196/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 90ms/step - loss: 0.5799 - accuracy: 0.8056 - val_loss: 0.6330 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 197/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 83ms/step - loss: 0.5792 - accuracy: 0.8056 - val_loss: 0.6313 - val_accuracy: 0.7500
Epoch 198/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 191ms/step - loss: 0.5785 - accuracy: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.6296 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 199/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 77ms/step - loss: 0.5779 - accuracy: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.6278 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 200/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 122ms/step - loss: 0.5772 - accuracy: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.6261 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 201/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 98ms/step - loss: 0.5765 - accuracy: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.6244 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 202/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 85ms/step - loss: 0.5758 - accuracy: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.6226 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 203/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 107ms/step - loss: 0.5752 - accuracy: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.6209 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 204/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 54ms/step - loss: 0.5745 - accuracy: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.6192 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 205/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 67ms/step - loss: 0.5738 - accuracy: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.6175 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 206/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 125ms/step - loss: 0.5731 - accuracy: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.6158 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 207/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 101ms/step - loss: 0.5725 - accuracy: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.6140 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 208/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 146ms/step - loss: 0.5718 - accuracy: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.6123 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 209/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 218ms/step - loss: 0.5711 - accuracy: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.6106 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 210/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 174ms/step - loss: 0.5704 - accuracy: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.6088 - val_accuracy: 1.0000```
````

Comment: So what is the exact problem?

Comment: The problem is, can mulitple epochs have the same accuracy? Why is the accuracy not changing for each epoch whether increasing or decreasing?

Comment: Because you have only 45 data points.

Comment: How are you compiling the model? Please provide minimal reproducible code to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code is insufficient to replicate on my side however, there can be 2 common reasons why the loss is decreasing and the accuracy not improving after a point :

1. There is overfitting . **Train the model on your train and test data separately** and check if it performs well on the train data , but NOT on the test data.

You can quickly use this code to check your data

```
#combining test and train data
df_combine = pd.concat([train, test], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
#dropping ‘target’ column as it is not present in the test
df_combine = df_combine.drop(‘target’, axis =1)
y = df_combine['is_train'].values #labels
x = df_combine.drop('is_train', axis=1).values #covariates or our independent variables
tst, trn = test.values, train.values

m = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1, max_depth=5, min_samples_leaf = 5)
predictions = np.zeros(y.shape) #creating an empty prediction array
```

If the performance with the train and test data is comparable, then this issue may not be there. Check the full code jist [here](https://github.com/erlendd/covariate-shift-adaption/blob/master/Supervised%20classification%20by%20covariate%20shift%20adaption.ipynb).

The related [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-dis-similar-are-my-train-and-test-data-56af3923de9b) can be referred as well.

[image: overfit/underfit]

2. The distribution of the train and test data need to be the same.

You can plot them separately and compare the graphs to verify that.

If not the same then some transformations like square/log/exponential need to be applied.